# Tabbing Order of Widgets

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Over a year ago I asked about recognising TABS when using a CharValidator(). This now works with a bespoke CharValidator(). However, the TAB order follows the order in which the widgets were created visiting them all including automatically generated/calculated ones (e.g. date, BMI). I would like to amend this order without reworking a large section of code also excluding non-relevant ones as mentioned. I have come across this piece of code:

```
order = (control1, control2, control3,......)
for i in range(len(order)  - 1):
    order[i+1].MoveAfterInTabOrder(order[i])
```

but with no clear indication of how to implement/call. A Google search has not come up with anything helpful'

Code is written in Python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: My problem is that I found this code snippet but with no indication of how to use it. When I put it immediately after the widget creation it had no effect. So my query was where do I place it and how do I call it (if not automatic).

Comment: you just put all you controls inside the order list. And then reshuffle it as you wish. The parameter for `MoveAfterInTabOrder` is the control after which you are moving. So in your case - order[i + 1] is the window that is moving and order[i] is the window that is being moved after. Meaning that if the order[i] has the focus, when you press TAB focus will be moved to order[i + 1].

Comment: See https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_window.html#a79e66079125e8420de269811bdb6f2b6 for the details.

Answer (score 0):

`Move{Before,After}InTabOrder()` functions do what you'd expect them to do, i.e. they move the window they're called on before or after the window passed to them as argument in the TAB order and this is indeed what you should use to change the TAB order without changing the order of creation.